# Error implementing spellchecker demo using vb in visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-code, nuget, hunspell

I am trying to integrate a spell checking routine with a web project.  I am using asp.net  in a Visual Studio environment.  Despite a lack of documentation, I will post the routine below.  The references are to the Nuget "Netspell" and "SpellChecker" packages, I have installed those to my project, and several other items that I don't really believe are the cause of the problem.  The diagnostic saying that the package is not available is frustrating after many attempts.  Here is the code:

```vb
Imports Netspell.SpellChecker

Module MainModule
    Sub Main()
        Dim checker As New SpellChecker()

        ' Initialize the dictionary with the path to the dictionary files
        checker.Dictionary.DictionaryFolder = "C:\user\Arise\source\arise\netspell\netspell.dictionaries"
        ' Check spelling
        Dim misspelledWords As ArrayList = checker.CheckText("Your text goes here mothr")

        ' Display misspelled words
        For Each word As String In misspelledWords
            Console.WriteLine("Misspelled word: " & word)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine() ' Keep console window open
    End Sub
End Module
```

I do not know where all the underlined words come from.  The only failure I get in VS studio is on the dim Checker statement.. Also, I have modified the code to suit a web project to no avail.

Tried modifying the code to suit various project types. I corrected several upper and lower case instances that were causing diagnostics to appear.  At this point I cannot try anything else because I am informed that the diagnostic "missing type" is merely indicating that the referenced package is missing.